# set php session variable using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Im new to ajax/jquery. so is there an easy way that when i click a cell with in the table, the value of it will be stored in a session variable.

thanks in advance

Comment: You could do an click event to to push the value to a phpfile. with ajax, but you are not stating what you have already tried

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the Q&A websites where we love enthusiastic people with thrilling questions though we even more love to get some inspiration of what you've tried beforehand.
As Iesus states you can send a AJAX request to the server doing whatever the server do when receiving requests. So in general: Yes it's possible - maybe you can narrow down your problem?

Comment: well to narrow it down. what i want to accomplish is that when i click a value from the table, the ajax/jquery will save the value from a session, that i will now call from a database where i can get the values from it, then print it.

Answer (score 7):

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
...
<head>
<body>
....
<table id="clickable"><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>
<script>
$('#clickable td').on('click', function(e){ $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourphppage.php',
    data: {sendCellValue: $(this).text()}
}); });
</script>
....
</body>
</html>
```

The table can be as large as you like, and the above script will send to your PHP page any cell that is clicked in the table that has the id "clickable". Note that if you want more than one clickable table, you should change it from an id to a class.

Then in yourphppage.php, (which given the above code must be in the same directory:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['cellValue'] = $_POST['sendCellValue'];
?>
```

Saving the information to a database is very different to a session. Do you need to differentiate who clicked what? Or just record what was clicked on, regardless of who clicked it?

If so, use the following instead of the second snippet above:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","my_db_username","pass1234");
mysql_select_db("my_db_name", $connection);

mysql_query('INSERT INTO TheTable (CellValue)
VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sendCellValue']).'")');
?>
```

For that you will want a table (called TheTable). It will need two columns. The first could be called "ID" or something similar. It will need to be set as "auto-incrementing", and its type must be "Integer". The second column must be called "CellValue", and its type can be set to "varchar" with 255 characters.

To output the information, so it can be printed, you should ask a new question on how to output a database table to HTML. In all likelihood you will probably not want to print the table as-is, so you should be specific about what it is people will be clicking on, i.e. is it text? Or a nummber? And if it's a number, what kind of number? Do you want to group the numbers and show a total number of clicks for each group? Etc, please be specific. You may need to change some of the above depending on what post-processing you want to do on the information in the table before you print it out. For example, you may need to change the second column's type from varchar to integer or float (and in that case you would need to change the PHP file as well).

Comment: okay. I'll try this one

Answer (score 5):

It can be as simple as this:

The following snippet send the value to a page where session variable can be set

```
$.post('sessionsetter.php', { 'fieldname' : 'sessionvariablename', 'value' : 'sessionvalue'});
```

Now 'sessionsetter.php' can be something like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[$_POST['fieldname']] = $_POST['value'];
```

Now, you can send as many variables you want to set as SESSION variable.

Comment: so uh.. where should i put the $.post inside a script in the head?

im completely new to ajax/jquery

Comment: @user2102316 well than get a book of JavaScript first you can also try try http://codecademy.com/.. than read some php books ... and than try juqery website .. its only process to learn .. spoon fiddling is never a good idea