# Put javascript variable to php supergloabal

Tags: javascript, php, variables, session

```
 var test=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
```

I want to put the javascript variable test into a php $_SESSION variable. I cannot figure out how to do it so can someone please help me?

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX

Comment: You could use document.cookie to set a cookie and get it via $_COOKIE.

Comment: You need to use ajax and posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053620/set-php-session-variable-using-ajax-jquery

Comment: Probably duplicate of 100 questions....

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go:

**JS**:

```
function saveMyValue(value) {

    $.post( "path/phpPage.php", { data1: value });
 }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['data1'])) {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['data1'];

 }

?>
```